# How can I check if OpenACC works on my computer?

Tags: openacc

I know that GCC 6.x has a decent OpenACC support. But I want to make sure if it works correctly on my computer. I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openacc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    acc_device_t dev = acc_get_device_type();
    int num = acc_get_device_num(dev);
    printf("%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `0`. Did I do something wrong? Or is there another way to verify that OpenACC works correctly on my computer?

Is there any way I can find out, what devices will be used by OpenACC in parallel regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change that to call `acc_get_num_devices(dev);`. Right now you're asking "which device am I using?" which always starts at 0, rather than "how many devices do I have?"